# Internal Service Error WordPress site live

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, internal-server-error

I'm trying to transfer my WordPress from a local to a live server. when I copied all the files to the FTP I keep on getting an internal service error. 
This is what my htaccess file says:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase rachelwebdesign.com/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . rachelwebdesign.com/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Please let me know if there is something I should change on this file and/or if there is any other files I should be looking at to fix this error.

All I found in my error_log was this:

```
[24-Jan-2016 16:49:52] PHP Fatal error:  require() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required '/home5/doeremix/public_html/rachelwebdesign/wp-includes/load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib64/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home5/doeremix/public_html/rachelwebdesign/wp-settings.php on line 21
[24-Jan-2016 16:49:57] PHP Fatal error:  require() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required '/home5/doeremix/public_html/rachelwebdesign/wp-includes/load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib64/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home5/doeremix/public_html/rachelwebdesign/wp-settings.php on line 21
```

I'm unsure if this could be my issue - or how I would change it.

Thanks in advance for all of your help.

Comment: Try removing the `.com` part at the two occurrences of `rachelwebdesign.com`

Comment: I just tried that, but it didn't help.

Comment: What would happen if you disable your .htaccess file temporarily?

Comment: I changed in my .htaccess file to /rachelwebdesign/: and now the front page is showing up, but my images are missing and when I try to click to any other pages on the site it gives my the internal service error again.

Comment: I also get the same result if I temporarily delete the .htaccess file. The first page only works - but the images don't show up, and when I click on the menu to go to the other pages - it gives me the internal service error again.

Comment: Your website probably has a bad URL setting, also, try to rebuild your htaccess file from within http://rachelwebdesign.com/wp-admin

Answer (score 0):

The links of your images are pointing to /localhost. When you transferred the website to the server did you change the internal links to the new one (rachelwebdesign.com) ?

Also try to update your permalinks to /%postname%/ under settings-permalinks.

To fix the internal service error add these lines to your wp-config.php

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
@ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

When you load your webpage it will show any possible errors, try to fix them to get rid of the internal service errors.  When finished change the value true to false and the 1 to 0.

Hopefully it will fix your problems.

This is the .htaccess file I always use without problems:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```